# How to fix BeautifulSoup breaking asynchronous execution of asyncio and aiohttp?

Tags: python, asynchronous, beautifulsoup, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using `asyncio` with `run_until_complete` and `asyncio.gather` to perform requests to multiple urls asynchronously.
To limit total request I am also using a `semaphore`.
I am validating the results of the `aiohttp` GET-request result then with `BeautifulSoup`.

Here is the code:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()
    except Exception as e:
        print(url, str(e))
        return False

async def validate_page(session, url):
    res = await fetch(session, url)
    if res:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
        except Exception:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            return False


async def validate_page_bounded(sem, session, url):
    async with sem:
        return await validate_page(session, url)

....
```

Strangely, as long as I comment-out the line

`soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')`

the code runs smoothly and performs the GET-requests asynchronously. But as soon as it's uncommented, it seems like aiohttp is just sending the GET-requests one-by-one waiting for each request to finish.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

> But as soon as [BeautifulSoup is] uncommented, it seems like aiohttp is just sending the GET-requests one-by-one waiting for each request to finish. Any idea why?

Because asyncio is single-threaded. If BeautifulSoup parsing takes a lot of CPU, that time cannot be used to service HTTP requests and responses, so your downloads get effectively serialized, or at least severely constrained. Fortunately, there is an easy way to fix it, just replace:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
```

with:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
soup = loop.run_in_executor(None, BeautifulSoup, res, 'lxml')
```

That will instruct asyncio to submit the parser to a separate thread pool, allowing other coroutines to proceed while BeautifulSoup is working, and resuming the current coroutine as soon as it's done.

With a bit of additional tweaking you can extend this approach to use multiprocessing and actually take advantage of multiple cores:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(8)

# Place the actual validation in a sync function that accepts a simple
# bytes object, and returns a bool (as opposed to a BeautifulSoup
# instance or such). Since these simple types are efficient to
# serialize, the function can run in a different process.
def do_validate(data):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return False
    # the rest of your validation code goes here
    # ...
    return True

async def validate_page(session, url):
    res = await fetch(session, url)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, do_validate, res)

# fetch and validate_page_bounded are unchanged
```

Comment: That does make sense, I just didn't think it had a big impact, since the actual calculation times for BeautifulSoup are only a fraction of the GET-request durations (0.05sec vs. 1 sec). But I will give it a try!

Comment: @Felix Since many people are using aiohttp for parallel downloads, it is very unlikely that aiohttp is causing GETs to proceed one by one. If this doesn't help you, my suggestion would be to try to create a minimal and still runnable example that still demonstrates this behavior, and include it in the question.